# Bypass Spring Security @preauthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm calling the following method from the web layer throw a logged in user that has the attached permission:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('list_users_permission')")
public List<UserDto> getAllUsers() {
    ........
}
```

But now I want to call it through a scheduler job, which means that I haven't a logged in user.

Is there a way to bypass this annotation **@PreAuthorize("hasRole('list_users_permission')")** or to create a virtual user with all the needed permissions ?

Comment: where are your users stored at? is the scheduler standalone app? can you add methods/classes to the application containing the secured method? where is your security configured to fetch the credentials from?

Comment: - Users are stored at DB
- Scheduler is not a standalone application. It's contained at the same web application.
- The secured method is the one I've attached above. It's only getting all users from DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make `getAllUsers()` delegate to a non-secured method:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('list_users_permission')")
public List<UserDto> getAllUsers() {
    return doGetAllUsers();
}

public List<UserDto> doGetAllUsers() {
    ...
}
```

Then make the scheduled code invoke `doGetAllUsers()`.